# How can I resize a filesystem to fit a bigger partition?

Tags: partitioning, filesystem

Using gnome-disk-utility

1. I've taken a filesystem image (15~GB)
2. destroyed the partition it was on and created a larger one (33~ GB)
3. restored the filesystem image on the new partition

now the filesystem is smaller than the partition it sits on, but gnome-disk-utility does not agree. I had 1,4GB free space when the partition was 15GB total, so now that partition is 33GB total it should really be 19,4GB free space!
[image: 1,4GB free should really be 19,4GB]
I think I need a terminal command (maybe resize2fs) to make the filesystem the same size of the new partition, can you please help?

P.s. I'm on Ubuntu 21.04 beta

Comment: Your picture identifies partition as Fedora. Fedora is off topic here. Edit your question and indicate if you are using Ubuntu and if so which version. If this question is about Ubuntu (and not Fedora), does this answer your question [How to resize partitions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)?

Comment: Sorry, i'm on ubuntu 21.04beta

Comment: Betas are off topic too!

Comment: ok, didn't know that, so what do I do now?

Comment: It looks like gnome disks added resizing feature some years ago. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll notice only supported releases of Ubuntu and flavors are on-topic for this site. For *hirsute* hippo [21.04] questions you'll need to use a development support site such as IRC (#ubuntu+1) or Ubuntu Forums, or wait until after release for this site (expected release date for Ubuntu 21.04 is 22 April 2021 (https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/hirsute-hippo-release-schedule/18539) when your question will be on-topic here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `resize2fs` is correct. You give it the name of the partition as its only argument, and it will look up the current size of the partition and extend the file system to that size.

Comment: Great, thank you! I wonder why gnome-disk-utility didn't allow me to do it graphically